# Mysql database dumps with foreign keys fails to populate internal system database

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL workbench to dump 4 databases with tables that reference each other. As a note, there are no current problems with the databases at all - everything works as expected. When I try various data exports from MySQL workbench and then import it to another PC with MySQL workbench, everything appears to be fine except that the system tables (such as information_schema) do not have any data.

On my working setup, if I run this query

```
SELECT k.COLUMN_NAME, k.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, k.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i 
        LEFT JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k ON i.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        WHERE i.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
        AND i.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'details'
        AND i.TABLE_NAME = 'locales'
```

I will get a whole bunch of information about fkey relationships.

After I dump and import these databases to another PC, and run this query again, I get the same amount of rows *but all data is NULL*. This tells me that during import, MySQL failed to properly set up these foreign keys. I am trying dumps with options like

- don't include data
- include data
- create schema

Well, that's about all I can really choose from.

When I investigate the tables in MySQL workbench, they *all* show proper foreign keys! But I need the above query to produce correct results because I use it in my PHP application to display foreign keys to the user.

Is there any way to get the information_schema tables to properly reflect the state of the system after an import?

Comment: You don't export the `information_schema` database, you usually don't need to. The target database has its own `information_schema` database. Why do you need the `information_schema` database?

Comment: @Progman After importing this database, and querying `information_schema` there are lots of entries full of NULL. So somehow this export/import fails miserably. Basically what the question says.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which specifically shows the problem you have. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. Show the result of your query above with the example table you have. Then show the SQL query which was generated to create the schema dump. Show the commands/actions on how you created the dump and how you imported it into your new database. And then show the result of your query in the new database after you have imported the schema dump.